# Getting Fee amount from Electrum Transaction using CLI

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bitcoin

I am trying to get the fee for a done transaction in Electrum: https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmdline.html

I can run:

```
# python3 Electrum-4.4.5/run_electrum getaddresshistory bc1qcq6dlt3xz2sq2kaqyc7c6wg....

    {
        "height": 800962,
        "tx_hash": "b7d2750862458b044fccc1072122da7161458fee7824286....."
    }
```

or deserialize the transaction

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "coinbase": false,
            "nsequence": 4294967293,
            "prevout_hash": "0015b11283a666be71df4cd72bb85f64ec4a23....",
            "prevout_n": 1,
            "scriptSig": "4730440220353a13e84a26cc2d35cd6e0a939d60b98b1a0a128b31....."
        }
    ],
    "locktime": 800936,
    "outputs": [
        {
            "address": "16NAxAtJiYLkmaQi21j...",
            "scriptpubkey": "76a9143ad9abc4cdf4....",
            "value_sats": 12600
        },
        {
            "address": "bc1qhzqfl0t54xc60std7r0rv...",
            "scriptpubkey": "0014b8809fbd74a9b1a7c....",
            "value_sats": 15000
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

Does the Electrum CLI supports that feature actually?